# How to calculate PRESS and $R^2_{predicted}$ in Stata automatically

Tags: stata, prediction

So I have two models and I want to calculate these statistics. Is there any package to calculate them in Stata?

[PRESS statistic (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PRESS_statistic)

And, if I am not mistaken.
$$
R^2_{predicted} = 1 - \frac{RESET}{ESS}
$$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
clear all

program define press, rclass
    syntax varlist(fv) [if] [in]        ///
    [fweight aweight pweight iweight] , ///
    [nodots]

    gettoken y x : varlist
    marksample touse
    preserve
    quietly keep if `touse'
    if "`weight'" != "" {
        local wgt "[`weight'`exp']"
    }

    tempvar pred temp prs
    quietly gen double `pred' = .
    if "`dots'" == "" _dots 0, title(Jackknife replications) reps(`=_N')
    forvalues i = 1/`=_N' {
        capture {
            reg `y' `x' `wgt' if _n != `i'
            predict double `temp'
            replace `pred' = `temp' in `i'
            drop `temp'
        }
        if "`dots'" == "" _dots `i' `=_rc > 0'
    }
    quietly gen double `prs' = (`y' - `pred')^2
    sum `prs', meanonly

    if "`dots'" == "" di _n _n
    di as txt "The predicted residual sum of squares is " as result r(sum)
    return scalar press = r(sum)
    restore
end

sysuse auto
press price mpg i.foreign
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have this error in Stata. `press price mpg i.foreign
invalid syntax
r(197);`

Comment: It runs without error message on my computer. What version of Stata are you using?

Comment: I use the 13.0 version of Stata

Comment: Then I really don't know what is going on. The only thing I can imagine is that something went wrong while you coppied the code. Maybe it helps to `set traced 1` and `set trace on` and inspect the output to find the error. That gives you a lot of output, and you start inspecting that near the error message.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with how Stata works, however I tried to copy your code into Do-file and it worked. Earlier I tried the command line. Thanks

Comment: Also, I'd like to ask what does the "i." mean in "i.foreign"?

Comment: It uses the factor variable notation, see `help fvvarlist`.

Answer (score 1):

For multilinear regression, the PRESS can also be computed as the sum of r(i)^2/(1-h(i))^2 where r(i) are the residuals and h(i) the hat values (the diagonal entries of the [hat matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_matrix), which is X*(X'*X)^-1*X', where X is the [design matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_matrix).

In Stata, call the following command `press`, without argument, after `regress`:

```
prog def press, rclass
    tempvar r h p
    predict `r', r
    predict `h', h
    gen `p'=(`r'/(1-`h'))^2
    sum `p', mean
    di in gr "PRESS = " in ye r(sum)
    ret sca press=r(sum)
end
```